# Like protobuf, but to text instead of binary

Tags: open-source, library, serialization

I want a serialization framework that generates source files to multiple programming languages from IDL with forward and backward compatibility, but it should be serialized to text, not to binary.

Serialized data should be reasonably compact (e.g. 50%-150% bigger that protobuf), but somewhat readable and typeable on keyboard.

It can use Protobuf's (or other well known framework's) IDL if needed.

Like base64-encoded protobuf, but where data is not opaque and can be manually decoded and modified in a meaningful way. Strings without special characters may be visible as themselves, numbers may be packed somehow (but not too much)...

Comment: what's wrong with JSON?

Comment: It's not based on IDL, there is no code generation (if three is acutally then post it as an answer). Also it's a bit verbose, I expect it to be much bigger than binary protobuf.

Comment: do you have a specific IDL in mind?

Comment: @chicks, Probably no, but if it shares protobuf's one it would be nicer.

Comment: base64-encoded data is not more manually decodable than protobuf. The drawback of protobuf I can say is: there are no name of fields inside the binary encoding, but thanks to this the format is really compact.